# Add arguments to get_the_terms for custom post types

Tags: custom-post-types, terms

When using get_the_terms to retrieve terms within a taxonomy for a custom post type you can't pass arguments, like so:

```
function custom_cat_function() {
    global $post;
    $args = array(
      'orderby'    => 'ID',
      'order'      => 'ASC',
    );
    $terms = get_the_terms($post->id, 'category', $args);
    $count = count( $terms );
    if ( $count > 0 ) {
        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            echo '<li>' . $term->name . '</li>';
        }
    }
}
```

all documentation points to other functions like get_terms, but get_terms retrieves ALL terms within a taxonomy, not just the terms for that single post (within a loop).

How do you properly pass arguments like the example above (I'm aware the example above is not right, but I wrote it as a baseline example of what needs to be achieved)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`get_the_terms` uses [`wp_get_object_terms`](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_get_object_terms) with defaults, which is orderby name ascending. You can use `wp_get_object_terms` directly if you want to set arguments differently.

```
$args = array(
    'orderby' => 'term_id'
);
$terms = wp_get_object_terms( get_the_ID(), 'category', $args );
```

Comment: was looking at using this but read in documentation "It should be noted that the results from wp_get_object_terms are not cached which will result in a db call everytime this function is called. For performance, functions like get_the_terms() (which the results of has been cached), should be used."

Comment: I think you have a choice between ordering terms yourself in php with `get_the_terms` or no cache and ordered the way you want via `wp_get_object_terms`